# How to select a child element of an element 2 steps behind?

Tags: jquery

How would I grab the value of the 'onclick' attribute from the button in the situation below?

```
<li>...<br><button onclick="x()">X</button></li>
<li>
<li onclick="monkey(this)"></li>
```

I have tried the following script but this does not feel right:

```
function monkey(src){
    console.log($(src).prevAll()[0].children('button')[0].attr('onclick'));
}
```

Comment: Please explain more exact what you want

Comment: Seeing your code it seems you forget close the second `<li>` tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `attr()` with `jQuery` object and you are using it with `DOM` object so do not use *indexer*, and calling prev() *two* time could give you the element you want

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/j57MP/)**

*Change*

```
console.log($(src).prevAll()[0].children('button')[0].attr('onclick'));
```

*To*

```
console.log($(src).prev().prev().children('button').attr('onclick'));
```

Comment: Ah... I see what you mean. Damn it, should not code at night... >.< Thanks for the correction, and your prompt response is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you HTML is exactly as your example you could do this:

```
$(src).prevAll()[0].find("button").attr('onclick')
```

---

Alternatively, if your `li` elements belong to a parent (which I imagine they do!) then you can do this:

```
$(src).parent().find("button").attr('onclick')
```

Both of these examples assume that there is only one `button` element present. If you have multiple then you need to be more specific

Comment: Hey, yeah, I considered going to parent and narrowing down from there, but it shouldn't have to come to that, it should be more direct. And YES! I do have a parent for the <li>', hahaha... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log($(src).parents('button')[0].prop('onclick'));
```

However, I'd look through your code and see if you can make this easier for yourself, such as attaching a click event handler to your list element and using appropriate classes.

Comment: You're right, I should simply use event handlers and what not, but the thing is I have this .js file here for a while now, and I've always coded in native JS, only recently got egged into jQuery, and from the little guidance I have, I'm probably doing it wrong by mixing the two... Good learning experience though...

Answer (score 0):

Give button a class say 'btn'

#### HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>...<br><button class="btn" onclick="x()">X</button></li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li onclick="monkey(this)"></li>
</ul>
```

#### Script

```
function monkey(src){
    console.log($('.btn', $(src).siblings()).attr('onclick'));
}
```

Comment: Nah, not what I'm looking for... Adding directly to the HTML defeats the purpose... Or rather, the purpose I'm looking at anyways... Still, your approach is valid and your answer technically sound. :)